# Can't get my express server up running on a Raspberry Pi zero

Tags: pi-zero-w, web-server, node.js

I am having trouble trying to get my express server to run on my Raspberry Pi zero w. I used the express-generator and ran `npm start` and this was the output:

> myapp@0.0.0 start /home/pi/MyApp
>
> node ./bin/www

and when I go to `localhost:3000` with another machine on the same network, I don't see the express default page. I am unsure if this is a Raspberry Pi problem or Express problem. If you think this belongs on Stack overflow, please let me know.

Here is some information on my setup:

- *Raspbian*: v10
- *Node*: v9.7.1
- *Express*: v4.16.1

I used express generator and it created a new directory with these inside:

```
app.js  
bin  
node_modules  
package.json  
package-lock.json  
public  
routes  
views
```

**app.js:**

```
var createError = require('http-errors');
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var logger = require('morgan');

var indexRouter = require('./routes/index');
var usersRouter = require('./routes/users');

var app = express();

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'jade');

app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.use('/', indexRouter);
app.use('/users', usersRouter);

// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  next(createError(404));
});

// error handler
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  // set locals, only providing error in development
  res.locals.message = err.message;
  res.locals.error = req.app.get('env') === 'development' ? err : {};

  // render the error page
  res.status(err.status || 500);
  res.render('error');
});

module.exports = app;
```

Comment: so ... app.js is the one and only javascript file? if so, why are you exporting anything? where is your `app.listen` ... i.e. the function that actually starts the express server? see https://expressjs.com/en/starter/hello-world.html for the basics of how to actually use express

Comment: Do you use root rights to listen to your server?

Comment: `and when I go to localhost:3000 with another machine on the same network` ... You are wrong , localhost means `local host`  pointing to `127.0.0.1` or `127.0.1.1` with `lo` interface,
therefore representing the local host and not accessible via an external machine without specific configuration. You should use your LAN addr : (ex get your IP: `sudo ifconfig wlan0`).

Comment: Use `sudo netstat -laputen` or 'sudo ss -ln' when your app is running. You should see the server listening on your LAN IP addr (ex: 192.168.X.X:3000 or 10.0.X.X:3000, etc) or on all interfaces `0.0.0.0:3000`. Yes stackoverflow is more appropriate because it's a RPi problems forums , not app/networking dev. problem.